# Formtastic default values on specific controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin, formtastic

What I currently have is a form that looks like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors*f.object.errors.keys
  f.inputs "Book Details" do
  f.input :id
  f.input :name
  f.input :min_quantity, hint: "usually 3", input_html: {value: 3}
end
```

I'm having issues with `f.input :min_quantity, hint: "usually 3", input_html: {value: 3}` When creating a new Book, I want the form to default that min_quantity to 3, which it does right now. However, when I am updating the book in the future, that field will automatically be set to 3 in the CMS, and override what was there before.

So my question is if there is a way to use `input_html: {value: 3}` only on the `create` action and not have it in `update`

Answer (score 0):

```
f.input :min_quantity, hint: "usually 3", f.object.new_record? : {input_html: {value: 3}} : {}
```